# Missing nets in PCB editor

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, netlists

I designed a schematic in KiCad 7.0.8, have verified that I have foot prints assigned to all components and when I hit F8, it switches over to the PCB editor, I get the "Changes To Be Applied" list with 0 warnings and 0 errors, I see that the footprints got imported but they all are by themselves, i.e. I don't see any nets between the pins & pads, how can I get the wires from the schematic correctly imported into the PCB editor?

View->Shaw Ratsnest is enabled, yet here's what I see: [image]

The nets appear to be connected properly:
[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance talking about the ratsnest?

Comment: Please post an image of the PCB showing the problem.

Comment: Can you show the schematics, and what ERC say?

Comment: Your first sentence is 80 words long. Please break it up into smaller chunks.

Comment: @winny Imagine saying it in one breath. *And I actually did.*

Comment: @MiNiMe As suggested above, running the ERC ("Electrical Rules Checker") actually uncovered a couple of issues in my schematic and after I corrected those, the Rats Nest appeared correctly as expected! Thanks! You can move the comment into an answer and I'll gladly accept! :)

Comment: There you go. Happy it worked out for you and now you got to know an excellent tool in the Kicad suite. In PCB new, there's a similar tool, DRC, use that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In schematics, run ERC and correct any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Are there nets on the pads though?

If you’re looking for a rat’s nest, it’s possible you have yours turned off. There’s a button on toolbar for “show ratsnest”. Also accessible through layer management toolbar.

Comment: The Layer toolbar is also part of the "Appearance Panel", often on the right margin if enabled, with tabs to select Layers/Object/Nets. The Ratnest visibility icon (eye), is under the Objects tab.